# An error occured in an Android progress bar 

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have created an Android application. In that program, I have two layouts. When I click the button in the first layout, it will display the second layout with the progress bar. My problem is the progress bar is placed in the first layout after I click the button. How do I fix this problem?

Here is my code:

```
// Get the increment value from the text box
myTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
s = myTitleText.getText().toString();

con=myTitleText.length();

//Convert the textvalue to a integer value
dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setMessage("Loading...");

// Set the progress to be horizontal
dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

// Reset the bar to the default value of 0
dialog.setProgress(0);

// Get the maximum value
int maximum=jstr.length();

// Set the maximum value
dialog.setMax(maximum);

// Display the progress bar
dialog.show();

// Create a thread for updating the progress bar
Thread background = new Thread (new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Enter the code to be run while displaying the progress bar.
            //
            // This example is just going to increment the progress bar:
            // So keep running until the progress value reaches maximum value
            while (dialog.getProgress()<= dialog.getMax()) {
                // Wait 500 ms between each update.
                Thread.sleep(500);

                // Activate the update handler
                progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
            }
        }
        catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
            // If something fails, do something smart
        }
    }
});

// Start the background thread
background.start();

// Handler for the background updating
progressHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        dialog.incrementProgressBy(con);
    }
};
```

Comment: I got the progressbar in second layout.but i want it in  first layout

Answer (score 0):

If you want the progress bar to appear on the first layout itself after the button click, then place the XML part of code for progress bar in that first layout.